# How to make this non-standard union ISO C++ compliant while retaining convenience of use?

Tags: c++

Consider a class:

```
template<typename Type>
class CVector2
{
public:
    union {
        struct { Type x; Type y; };
        Type v[2];
    };

       // A bunch of methods for vector manipulation follow
}
```

It can be used as so:

```
CVector2<int> vec;
vec.x = 1;
vec.y = rand();
// ...
vec.v[rand() & 1] = vec.x;
```

The problem is, this union is not standard C++ because structs are not named. I can only see 1 way to make it standard - name the structures:

```
union {
        struct { Type x; Type y; } xy;
        Type v[2];
      };
```

Then I either have to make any vector fields access longer:

```
CVector2<int> vec;
vec.xy.x = 1;
vec.xy.y = rand();
// ...
vec.v[rand() & 1] = vec.xy.x;
```

Or I have to declare convenience methods, which helps, but access can still get cumbersome in complex usecases because of extra braces:

```
class CVector2
{
public:
    union {
        struct { Type x; Type y; };
        Type v[2];
    };

    Type& x() {return xy.x;}
    const Type& x() const {return xy.x;}
    Type& y() {return xy.y;}
    const Type& y() const {return xy.y;}
}
```

Usage example:

```
void setGeometry (CVector2<int> p1, CVector2<int> p2)
{
   setGeometry(CRect(CPoint(p1.x(), p1.y()), CPoint(p2.x(), p2.y())));
}
```

Is there any better way to make the CVector2 class compile with -pedantic-errors that I am missing?

Comment: Don't use a union but provide an `operator[]`?

Comment: Eliminating the union also eliminates the UB due to accessing inactive union members.

Comment: The C++ way to provide an alias is by using a reference. `Type& y = v[1]`, basically.

Answer (score 1):

Well, even if you are not stating it explicitly, I assume the purpose of your union is to perform  reinterpretation of an array as a pair of separate objects (and the other way around). I just don't see what other use such union might have, considering that in both cases it stores the same number of objects of the same type. This assumption is also supported by the following line in your code samples

```
vec.v[rand() & 1] = vec.xy.x;
```

If that is indeed the intended usage, the it cannot possibly be made "compliant". In C++ this kind of access causes *undefined behavior* regardless of whether your struct is named or not.

In C++ language only one member of the union is active at each moment in time - the last member that was written to. You are allowed to read that active member, bit you are are not allowed to read  other members of the union. In C++ language unions cannot be used to "reinterpret" memory, even if "reinterpretation" does not change the target type.

C language eventually relaxed its long-standing restrictions on this sort of union usage, but C++ never did. In C++ it is illegal to access "inactive" members of a union.

Comment: I don't understand. Isn't `union` simply a way to provide alternate aliases (possibly of different types) to the same memory? And what exactly causes undefined behavior? I've seen unions used exactly like this in A LOT of libraries and it works.

Comment: @Violet Giraffe: Absolutely not. The purpose of union is to "mutiplex"/"timeshare" memory usage. I.e. you can store different objects during different periods of time in the same memory region. The purpose of this is to save memory. Unions are not intended to be used for aliasing/reinterpretation. You are not allowed to write data into one member of the union and the read it through another member. That's UB. In C this [originally illegal] "aliasing" usage was eventually legalized (due to popular demand), but not in C++.

Comment: @Violet Giraffe: What specific "aliasing" do you want to achieve? Access an array as a pair of separate objects? Strictly speaking, I don't see why anyone would want to do something like that. Your array is already a pair of objects (with index-based selection). Build a function-based interface on top of it, if you don't like index interface. As for general reinterpretation... the "safest" way to reinterpret an object of one type as an object of another type is to `memcpy` one to another.